# How do you tell the Azure Mobile App .NET backend not to serialize a property?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Note: *this question is not about how to exclude a property from being serialized by the client.  This can be done using [JsonIgnore].   The same technique does not seem to work on the server.   Read on...*

On my .NET backend I have some properties that are only relevant to server code.   They get persisted by Entity Framework in the database like other properties but don't need to get serialized and sent across to the client.

I tried decorating said properties with [JsonIgnore] but they are still included in the JSON.

I also tried [IgnoreDataMember] but get an exception: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named *(the property with [IgnoreDataMember])*"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what is happening here, but when faced with the same problem everything worked out for me once I replaced [IgnoreDataMember] with both [JsonIgnore] and [XmlIgnore].

It appears that [IgnoreDataMember] does not work with virtual lazy-loaded properties.

Comment: didn't work for me. This property still appears in the response